# why every time I sort the rows and after that the columns of a matrix, the rows still stay sorted

Tags: sorting, matrix

We have a matrix A=(a_ij). We sort every row of A in increasing order and after that we sort every column in increasing order. Why every time I do that, the rows stay sorted? Can someone give an explanation or a contra example or a proof or whatever?

Comment: After thinking about that for 1 hour, I'm tempted to say "that's trivial" ;-) but I'm looking forward to see whether someone comes up with a nice proof for that one, so +1...